# Launch an action in Eclipse RCP at startup

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP plug-in and I have configured the help system to run within this plug-in. I can access it from the Help menu.

Now I want to launch the "Dynamic Help" action by default at startup. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Solved this by using the WorkbenchAdvisor implementation:

```
@Override
public void postStartup() {
    IWorkbenchHelpSystem help = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem();
    help.displayDynamicHelp();
}
```

The Startup extension proved futile.

Comment: "This is better than the org.eclipse.ui.startup extension although in an RCP app, it really doesn't matter if its your app.

In general we discourage the use of ui.startup in plugins to the IDE ... there are very few reasons to start up your plugin before a user action, and you don't want to start up a plugin with UI contributions (views, actions, menu contributions) as the framework is free to load all of your contributions after your plugin starts up."

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [org.eclipse.ui.startup](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_startup.html?resultof=%22%6f%72%67%2e%65%63%6c%69%70%73%65%2e%75%69%2e%73%74%61%72%74%75%70%22%20) extension and implement the `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup` interface that allows you to run code once the workbench has initialized.

Comment: Sweet thanks. I have also found this: PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem()