# Is it possible to trigger a sequence of actions in RCP-Plugin without plugins activation?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

If I activate an Eclipse plugin (e.g. by clicking on a command from the plug-in in a menu) a number of actions is automatically triggering - like setting preferences, etc.

I would like to ask if is it possible to activate a plug-in automatically at the Eclipse startup without clicking on any actions?

Possible duplicate: [Launch an action in Eclipse RCP at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220586/launch-an-action-in-eclipse-rcp-at-startup)

I'm not sure if is is the same case like mine. If it is, then sorry for duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is not totally clear to me what you mean, but it does seem to be an exact duplicate as far as I can see...]

If you want to start an Eclipse plug-in as Eclipse is started, you can either use either start-levels of OGSi or use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point... The frmer is the most general, whereas later is probably the easiest if you can change the `plugin.xml` of the plug-in...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check it. I'd also say "sorry" for poor explaination of my problem.

Comment: I tried startup extension point and that was it. Thanks a lot!